# Responsive iFrame not fitting container

Tags: html, css, iframe, containers

I have an iFrame on my site that is responsive, however when viewing it on most non-mobile screens it doesnt fit the size of the container. How might I get the iFrame to stretch to the container size or get the container to not go farther than my iFrames current max size? Thanks in advance.

The site is [Waterlessbuddys.com](http://www.waterlessbuddys.com) scroll down just slightly and you will find the iFrame.

```css
.embeded-video {
    position: relative
}

.embeded-video .ratio-img {
    display: block;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: auto !important;
}

.embeded-video IFRAME {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="embeded-video">
    <img class="ratio-img" src="http://placehold.it/16x9" alt="16:9 Image" />
    <iframe src="http://abc11.com/video/embed/?pid=835255"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: what happens if you put width:100% in the actual iframe tag?

Comment: You using jQuery on the site? If so, you can just resize the iframes width on window resize

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Is this what you want ?
If so, you could continue reading..

1. set `<body>` in iframe: `style=margin:0`
2. set `<div itemprop="video" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/VideoObject">`  : `style=position:relative;display:block`

Done!